# libpam-ldapd - LDAP authentication on Debian 11 not working

Tags: linux, debian, authentication, openldap

I saw several other questions here regarding a similar issue - but I haven't found something that actually worked for me.

My goal is to authenticate (mainly for SSH) all Debian maschines against an UCS (OpenLDAP) directory - in the future only when the user is member of an specific ldap group. But I'm currently struggeling to make it even work without an groupmembership.

I always get the error:

```
nslcd: [7b23c6] <authc="test"> DEBUG: ldap_sasl_bind("uid=test,cn=users,dc=securitywho,dc=local","***") (uri="ldap://ldap.securitywho.local") (ppolicy=yes)
nslcd: [7b23c6] <authc="test"> DEBUG: ldap_parse_result() result: Invalid credentials
nslcd: [7b23c6] <authc="test"> DEBUG: failed to bind to LDAP server ldap://ldap.securitywho.local: Invalid credentials
nslcd: [7b23c6] <authc="test"> DEBUG: ldap_unbind()
nslcd: [7b23c6] <authc="test"> uid=test,cn=users,dc=securitywho,dc=local: Invalid credentials
nslcd: [7b23c6] <authc="test"> DEBUG: myldap_search(base="cn=users,dc=securitywho,dc=local", filter="(&(objectClass=*)(uid=test))")
nslcd: [7b23c6] <authc="test"> DEBUG: ldap_result(): uid=test,cn=users,dc=securitywho,dc=local
```

The bind user is working, I did check everything with an ldapsearch command - there everything is working fine with the bind user and if I use an wrong password the debug shows an error that the bind function is not working.

Ldapsearch used - and it is working:

```
ldapsearch -x -H ldap://ldap.securitywho.local -D "uid=srv_linux,cn=users,dc=securitywho,dc=local" -b cn=users,dc=securitywho,dc=local -W
```

Snip from the output:

```
# test, users, securitywho.local
dn: uid=test,cn=users,dc=securitywho,dc=local
krb5MaxLife: 86400
krb5MaxRenew: 604800
uid: test
uidNumber: 2008
sn: test
gecos: test
displayName: test
homeDirectory: /home/test
loginShell: /bin/bash
mailForwardCopyToSelf: 0
cn: test
krb5PrincipalName: test@SECURITYWHO.LOCAL
shadowLastChange: 18992
sambaBadPasswordCount: 0
sambaBadPasswordTime: 0
sambaAcctFlags: [U          ]
objectClass: shadowAccount
objectClass: top
objectClass: sambaSamAccount
objectClass: automount
objectClass: univentionPWHistory
objectClass: person
objectClass: krb5KDCEntry
objectClass: univentionObject
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: krb5Principal
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: univentionMail
objectClass: posixAccount
sambaSID: S-1-5-21-258973841-725078507-1497259816-5016
gidNumber: 5001
sambaPrimaryGroupSID: S-1-5-21-258973841-725078507-1497259816-513
univentionObjectType: users/user
```

Just to verify that my testuser is working I ran the ldapsearch command with the testuser - everything worked here as well. I checked that with several accounts in the OpenLDAP directory, all worked here but none when I tried it for SSH.

```
ldapsearch -x -H ldap://ldap.securitywho.local -D "uid=test,cn=users,dc=securitywho,dc=local" -b cn=users,dc=securitywho,dc=local -W
```

Config /etc/nslcd.conf

```
# /etc/nslcd.conf
# nslcd configuration file. See nslcd.conf(5)
# for details.

# The user and group nslcd should run as.
uid nslcd
gid nslcd

# The location at which the LDAP server(s) should be reachable.
uri ldap://ldap.securitywho.local

# The search base that will be used for all queries.
base cn=users,dc=securitywho,dc=local

# The LDAP protocol version to use.
#ldap_version 3

# The DN to bind with for normal lookups.
binddn uid=srv_linux,cn=users,dc=securitywho,dc=local
bindpw <SUPERSECUREPASSWORD>

# The DN used for password modifications by root.
#rootpwmoddn cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com

# SSL options
#ssl off
#tls_reqcert never
#tls_cacertfile /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt

# The search scope.
#scope sub
filter passwd (objectClass=*)
map    passwd uid              uid

filter shadow (objectClass=*)
map    shadow uid              uid
```

Complete Debug Output of nslcd:

```
root@ipam:~# nslcd -d
nslcd: DEBUG: NSS_LDAP nss-pam-ldapd 0.9.11
nslcd: DEBUG: CFG: threads 5
nslcd: DEBUG: CFG: uid nslcd
nslcd: DEBUG: CFG: gid 117
nslcd: DEBUG: CFG: uri ldap://ldap.securitywho.local
nslcd: DEBUG: CFG: ldap_version 3
nslcd: DEBUG: CFG: binddn uid=srv_linux,cn=users,dc=securitywho,dc=local
nslcd: DEBUG: CFG: bindpw ***
nslcd: DEBUG: CFG: base cn=users,dc=securitywho,dc=local
nslcd: DEBUG: CFG: scope sub
nslcd: DEBUG: CFG: deref never
nslcd: DEBUG: CFG: referrals yes
nslcd: DEBUG: CFG: filter aliases (objectClass=nisMailAlias)
nslcd: DEBUG: CFG: filter ethers (objectClass=ieee802Device)
nslcd: DEBUG: CFG: filter group (objectClass=posixGroup)
nslcd: DEBUG: CFG: filter hosts (objectClass=ipHost)
nslcd: DEBUG: CFG: filter netgroup (objectClass=nisNetgroup)
nslcd: DEBUG: CFG: filter networks (objectClass=ipNetwork)
nslcd: DEBUG: CFG: filter passwd (objectClass=*)
nslcd: DEBUG: CFG: filter protocols (objectClass=ipProtocol)
nslcd: DEBUG: CFG: filter rpc (objectClass=oncRpc)
nslcd: DEBUG: CFG: filter services (objectClass=ipService)
nslcd: DEBUG: CFG: filter shadow (objectClass=*)
nslcd: DEBUG: CFG: map group userPassword "*"
nslcd: DEBUG: CFG: map passwd userPassword "*"
nslcd: DEBUG: CFG: map passwd gecos "${gecos:-$cn}"
nslcd: DEBUG: CFG: map shadow userPassword "*"
nslcd: DEBUG: CFG: map shadow shadowLastChange "${shadowLastChange:--1}"
nslcd: DEBUG: CFG: map shadow shadowMin "${shadowMin:--1}"
nslcd: DEBUG: CFG: map shadow shadowMax "${shadowMax:--1}"
nslcd: DEBUG: CFG: map shadow shadowWarning "${shadowWarning:--1}"
nslcd: DEBUG: CFG: map shadow shadowInactive "${shadowInactive:--1}"
nslcd: DEBUG: CFG: map shadow shadowExpire "${shadowExpire:--1}"
nslcd: DEBUG: CFG: map shadow shadowFlag "${shadowFlag:-0}"
nslcd: DEBUG: CFG: pam_authc_ppolicy yes
nslcd: DEBUG: CFG: bind_timelimit 10
nslcd: DEBUG: CFG: timelimit 0
nslcd: DEBUG: CFG: idle_timelimit 0
nslcd: DEBUG: CFG: reconnect_sleeptime 1
nslcd: DEBUG: CFG: reconnect_retrytime 10
nslcd: DEBUG: CFG: ssl off
nslcd: DEBUG: CFG: tls_reqcert demand
nslcd: DEBUG: CFG: pagesize 0
nslcd: DEBUG: CFG: nss_min_uid 0
nslcd: DEBUG: CFG: nss_uid_offset 0
nslcd: DEBUG: CFG: nss_gid_offset 0
nslcd: DEBUG: CFG: nss_nested_groups no
nslcd: DEBUG: CFG: nss_getgrent_skipmembers no
nslcd: DEBUG: CFG: nss_disable_enumeration no
nslcd: DEBUG: CFG: validnames /^[a-z0-9._@$()]([a-z0-9._@$() \~-]*[a-z0-9._@$()~-])?$/i
nslcd: DEBUG: CFG: ignorecase no
nslcd: DEBUG: CFG: pam_authc_search BASE
nslcd: DEBUG: CFG: cache dn2uid 15m 15m
nslcd: version 0.9.11 starting
nslcd: DEBUG: initgroups("nslcd",117) done
nslcd: DEBUG: setgid(117) done
nslcd: DEBUG: setuid(110) done
nslcd: DEBUG: unlink() of /var/run/nslcd/socket failed (ignored): No such file or directory
nslcd: accepting connections
nslcd: [8b4567] DEBUG: connection from  pid=896662 uid=0 gid=0
nslcd: [8b4567] <authc="test"> DEBUG: nslcd_pam_authc("test","sshd","***")
nslcd: [8b4567] <authc="test"> DEBUG: myldap_search(base="cn=users,dc=securitywho,dc=local", filter="(&(objectClass=*)(uid=test))")
nslcd: [8b4567] <authc="test"> DEBUG: ldap_initialize(ldap://ldap.securitywho.local)
nslcd: [8b4567] <authc="test"> DEBUG: ldap_set_rebind_proc()
nslcd: [8b4567] <authc="test"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION,3)
nslcd: [8b4567] <authc="test"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_DEREF,0)
nslcd: [8b4567] <authc="test"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_TIMELIMIT,0)
nslcd: [8b4567] <authc="test"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_TIMEOUT,0)
nslcd: [8b4567] <authc="test"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_NETWORK_TIMEOUT,0)
nslcd: [8b4567] <authc="test"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS,LDAP_OPT_ON)
nslcd: [8b4567] <authc="test"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_RESTART,LDAP_OPT_ON)
nslcd: [8b4567] <authc="test"> DEBUG: ldap_simple_bind_s("uid=srv_linux,cn=users,dc=securitywho,dc=local","***") (uri="ldap://ldap.securitywho.local")
nslcd: [8b4567] <authc="test"> DEBUG: ldap_result(): uid=test,cn=users,dc=securitywho,dc=local
nslcd: [8b4567] <authc="test"> DEBUG: myldap_search(base="uid=test,cn=users,dc=securitywho,dc=local", filter="(objectClass=*)")
nslcd: [8b4567] <authc="test"> DEBUG: ldap_initialize(ldap://ldap.securitywho.local)
nslcd: [8b4567] <authc="test"> DEBUG: ldap_set_rebind_proc()
nslcd: [8b4567] <authc="test"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION,3)
nslcd: [8b4567] <authc="test"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_DEREF,0)
nslcd: [8b4567] <authc="test"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_TIMELIMIT,0)
nslcd: [8b4567] <authc="test"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_TIMEOUT,0)
nslcd: [8b4567] <authc="test"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_NETWORK_TIMEOUT,0)
nslcd: [8b4567] <authc="test"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS,LDAP_OPT_ON)
nslcd: [8b4567] <authc="test"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_RESTART,LDAP_OPT_ON)
nslcd: [8b4567] <authc="test"> DEBUG: ldap_sasl_bind("uid=test,cn=users,dc=securitywho,dc=local","***") (uri="ldap://ldap.securitywho.local") (ppolicy=yes)
nslcd: [8b4567] <authc="test"> DEBUG: ldap_parse_result() result: Invalid credentials
nslcd: [8b4567] <authc="test"> DEBUG: failed to bind to LDAP server ldap://ldap.securitywho.local: Invalid credentials
nslcd: [8b4567] <authc="test"> DEBUG: ldap_unbind()
nslcd: [8b4567] <authc="test"> uid=test,cn=users,dc=securitywho,dc=local: Invalid credentials
nslcd: [8b4567] <authc="test"> DEBUG: myldap_search(base="cn=users,dc=securitywho,dc=local", filter="(&(objectClass=*)(uid=test))")
nslcd: [8b4567] <authc="test"> DEBUG: ldap_result(): uid=test,cn=users,dc=securitywho,dc=local
```

What I tried is to play around with the "search scope" in the /etc/nslcd.conf but no combination made it work. What I currently don't see any configuration issue - does someone had the same issue or could help me out?
I installed everything with:

```
apt-get install libpam-ldapd
```

Answer (score 1):

After several more hours, wireshark debugs showed that BIND-Request for the BIND-User was correctly send to the ldapserver (BIND with simple auth --> no encryption). But my test-user had not the real password send to the ldap server, that means the authentication had to be not successfull. --> Tests done with SSH.

I tried to login to the local console and saw, that the login was now successfull regarding the nslcd debug - but /var/log/auth.log showed :

```
Jan  1 14:01:43 ipam login[489]: pam_unix(login:auth): check pass; user unknown
Jan  1 14:01:43 ipam login[489]: pam_unix(login:auth): authentication failure; logname=LOGIN uid=0 euid=0 tty=/dev/tty1 ruser= rhost=
Jan  1 14:01:43 ipam login[489]: pam_unix(login:account): could not identify user (from getpwnam(test))
Jan  1 14:01:43 ipam login[489]: Authentication failure
```

But now everything is working just fine - how I fixed it?
--> Reboot.

No more configuration changes had to be done, my configuration in the inital post was correct and is working fine now.